# Migration from old(Nuget.Core) to new client sdk(NuGet.Packaging & NuGet.Protocol)

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

In our old application we are using the following interfaces from NuGet.Core library.

```
IPackage
IPackageLookup
IPackageRepository
IPackageAssemblyReference
IPackagePathResolver
```

In the new '**NuGet.Packaging**' library we could only identify the '`IPackageMetadata` & `PackageBuilder`' classes. We need the migrating information about the above mentioned interfaces in the new client SDK (NuGet.Packaging & NuGet.Protocol).

**FYI:** We tried using `IPackageMetadata`, thought which is equivalent to old `IPackage` interface. In our old application, we used the following two methods in many places which belongs to `IPackage`.

```
IEnumerable<IPackageFile> GetFiles();
Stream GetStream();
```

Also struggling to find the migration options for these two methods.

It will be helpful, if someone provide the guide information (any URL or sample) about all the class/interface and methods of the new nuget SDK.

Please help us here for migrating to new client SDK.